# Having troubles in ordering search results using Lucene

Tags: c#, lucene, dynamics-crm-2011, lucene.net, adxstudio-portals

I am running search query as following to bring results from Dynamics CRM. Search is working fine but it is brining results based on relevance. We want  to order them in descending order of 'createdon' field. As we are displaying only 10 results per page, so I can't sort the result returned by this query.

Is there any way to order based on a field?

```
public IEnumerable<SearchResult> Search(string term, int? pageNumber, int 
        pageSize, out int totalHits, IEnumerable<string> logicalName)
{
    var searchProvider = SearchManager.Provider;
    var query = new CrmEntityQuery(term, pageNumber.GetValueOrDefault(1), pageSize, logicalNames);

    return GetSearchResults(out totalHits, searchProvider, query);        
}

private IEnumerable<SearchResult> GetSearchResults(out int totalHits, 
                 SearchProvider searchProvider, CrmEntityQuery query)
{
    using (ICrmEntityIndexSearcher searcher = searchProvider.GetIndexSearcher())
    {                
        Portal.StoreRequestItem("SearchDeduplicateListForAuthorisation", new List<Guid>());
        var results = searcher.Search(query);
        totalHits = results.ApproximateTotalHits;

        return from x in results
             select new SearchResult(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not used Lucene myself, so cant comment on that.

However, if you were doing this in basic CRM. You would use a `QueryExpression` with an `OrderExpression`. Then when you page the results they are paged in order.

Here is an example of a `QueryExpression`, with an `OrderExpression`, and paging.

[Page large result sets with QueryExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327917.aspx)

Presumably at some point the data is being pulled out of CRM, either within Lucene, or your own code, maybe in `CrmEntityQuery`? Then you can add the sort there.

Comment: thanks. Actually I am searching multiple queries like (kbArticle, Webpages, Incidents etc). So If I am using QueryExpression it will be very expensive query I think.

Comment: Well how does Lucene retrieve data from CRM? Presumably either via the a web service call - in which case it will have the same performance concern. Perhaps it's going direct to SQL? In which case you apply a order to the SQL query. Given Lucene is a search engine library I would be surprised if it doesn't support ordering of results. It's not clear where the actual problem is here.

Comment: No, I don't think Lucene supports ordering. https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy Searches

Comment: How does Lucene get the data it then searches on?

Comment: ADX Portal's SearchProvider is using Lucene and I can't confirm that how are they querying underneath but they must be using CRM Web Services. The search provider can index any entity that has been customized with a view with the name "Portal Search".

Comment: Even if I run Query Expression to extract results from all the entities in question, how the paging will work?